# Please correct my Android Java code using an onkey/onclick listeners on my Dialog

Tags: java, android, string, dialog, listener

I am triggering a dialog for password verification and I cant figure out why I cause an exception when an incorrect password is entered. Need some Jedi Masters to assist this Padewan.

```
@Override
private void LaunchPwdDialog(){
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
    final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.edtPasswordInput);
    alertDialogBuilder
    .setCancelable(true)
    .setPositiveButton("Finish", 
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
        if (userInput.getText().toString().compareTo(strAdminPassword) == 0){
                disableKioskMode();
                    }
            else{
                Log.i(TAG, "Function LaunchPwdDialog - Admin password incorrect. User entered: " + edt.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                disableKioskMode();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
    .setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override 
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                    if (userInput.getText().toString().compareTo(strAdminPassword) == 0)
                    {
                        disableKioskMode();
                        userInput.setText("");
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Function LaunchPwdDialog - Admin password incorrect. User entered: " + edt.getText().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (CurrentAttempt % MaxAttempts == 0) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "You are unauthorised to access this feature.");
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You are unauthorised to access this feature.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                return false;
            }
        });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I've got it successfully executing the disableKioskMode() function upon successful verification of the password but if i enter nothing or the wrong password, then it crashes. Not sure if it helps but heres the logcat:

```
06-01 05:55:24.910 12311 12311 D   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               Shutting down VM
06-01 05:55:24.910 12311 12311 W   dalvikvm com.androiddev.kiosk                     threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41759c08)
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               Process: com.androiddev.kiosk, PID: 12311
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               java.lang.NullPointerException
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               at com.androiddev.kiosk.KioskLauncher$100000000.onClick(KioskLauncher.java:413)
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:170)
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
06-01 05:55:24.915 12311 12311 E   AndroidRuntime com.androiddev.kiosk               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `userInput.getText().toString()` is null before making any operations on it.

Comment: I did have that on previous edits.. the crash happens when I enter the wrong password too.

Answer (score 1):

When user inputs wrong password you try to log following variable into LogCat;

```
edt.getText().toString()
```

Should it be

```
userInput.getText().toString()
```

If you want to log the password user entered?

Comment: OMG you're right Im so embarrassed and ashamed that i spent hours with no luck!  I gotta stop coding from an android tablet! Cant believe the log was causing the exception!